# LinkExtraction for Scrapy - Global deny?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am crawling a site which has ?locale=en or locale=jp...

I am only interested to crawl sites without locale specified in the url.

Currently I have this:

```
  # More specific ones at the top please
  # In general, deny all locale specified links
  rules = (  
      # Matches looks
      # http://lookbook.nu/look/4273137-Galla-Spectrum-Yellow
      Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/look/\d+'), deny=('\?locale=')), callback='parse_look'),

      # Matches all looks page under user overview, 
      Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/user/\d+[^/]+/looks/?$'), deny=('\?locale=')), 
          callback='parse_model_looks'),
      Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/user/\d+[^/]+/looks\?page=\d+$'), deny=('\?locale=')), 
          callback='parse_model_looks'),

      # Matches all user overview pages
      Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/user/\d+[^/]*/?$'), deny=('\?locale=')), 
          callback='parse_model_overview'),
```

I am repeating deny everywhere.

There's gotta be a better way right?

I tried doing a general rule to deny all \?locale= but that didn't work.

Comment: How about writing a function that constructs the Rule and always passes the deny parameter. Then use this in the rules tuple. E.g. rules = (mkrule(regex1, callback1), mkrule(regex2, callback2),...)

Answer (score 2):

You can build a complex "allow" regex but writing regex is often painful.
You can also use: the process_links method as describe here:
https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=process_links

This will open the possibility to call url parser and analyze parameters:

```
  Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/look/\d+')),
      process_links='process_links', 
      callback='parse_look')

def process_links(self,links):
    return [link for link in links if self.valid_links(link))

def valid_links(self,link):
    import urlparse
    urlp=urlparse.urlparse(link.url)
    querydict=urlparse.parse_qs(urlp.query)
    return "locale" not in querydict
```

This is a much safer technique to check for parameters